# Locked objects while importing dump file

Tags: oracle12c, datapump, impdp

I am trying to import a dump file using impdp Data Pump command. Unfortunately I have a few locked objects.
How can I unlock them and proceed with the import ?

Thanks in advance.
Nikola Neykov

Comment: 1. Better to add the error info as part of the question. 2. Try [`ignore=y`](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1492331695311). 3. It could be due to [space issue](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/26704870/Why-does-IMPDP-hang-after-INDEXES.html). 4. If its ok you can import the objects into another schema using [remap_schema](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SUTIL/GUID-619809A6-1966-42D6-9ACC-A3E0ADC36523.htm#SUTIL927)

Comment: I am using the following parameters: full=Y ignore=Y exclude=user cluster=n data_options=skip_constraint_errors. It does not show any error, it just freezes and that is it.